# Convert May 13, 2012 12:00:00 AM to 13/05/2012 in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

How to convert Convert May 13, 2012 12:00:00 AM to 13/05/2012  using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
var d = new Date("May 13, 2012 12:00:00 AM");
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
var formatedDate=(curr_date<10 ? "0"+curr_date:curr_date) + "/" + (curr_month<10? "0"+curr_month:curr_month ) + "/" + curr_year;
console.log(formatedDate);
```

Comment: No, don't. Parsing of non–standard date strings is implementation dependent, there is no specification requiring *Date.parse* (which is what is used when a string is passed to Date) to correctly parse that string. It should be manually parsed.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally recommended to not parse date strings, even those mentioned in ECMA-262 due to browser inconsistencies. You can use a library, but the format in the OP is not difficult:

```js
    function parseMMMDY(s) {
      var b = s.toLowerCase().match(/\w+/g);
      var months = {jan:'01',feb:'02',mar:'03',apr:'04',may:'05',jun:'06',
                    jul:'07',aug:'08',sep:'09',oct:'10',nov:'11',dec:'12'};
      return b && b[1] + '/' + months[b[0]] + '/' + b[2];
    } 

    var s = 'May 13, 2012 12:00:00 AM'

    document.write(parseMMMDY(s)); // 13/05/2012
```

If you need a Date object and parsing of the time component is also required, that isn't difficult either.

Comment: Cool, another drive–by down voter without the courage of their convictions to post a reason. I'll take that as an up vote then. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could consider use a library to do that convert instead of convert it yourself.

[moment.js](http://momentjs.com) is a great lib to do such thing. You just need oneline.

```
moment('May 13, 2012 12:00:00').format('DD/MM/YYYY')
```

You only need change the format string if you need use another format without change other code.